# Unicode issue with makemessages --all Django 1.6.2 Python 3.3

Tags: django, python-3.x, unicode, gettext

Upgrading a project from **Python 2.7** -> **3.3.1** and **Django 1.4** -> **1.6.2**.

After updating code our application is running again *(in py3)*.
Translations are being pulled from **.mo** files.

The only issue is that our old **.po** files cannot be used with

`django-admin.py makemessages -a`

It displays a lovely

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...`

We can run `makemessages` for the first time and get the skeleton files. Once we add any translations that are non-ASCII (ǹ, è, etc.) to the `msgstr` values, `makemessages` fails to complete.
*(If we run makemessages with higher verbosity templates with any NON-ASCII characters are skipped.)*

I've found bug reports for a similar issue, but they're back in the 1.3.x versions, but nothing really for the above versions.

---

**Update, more info:**

Here's where the exception is happening:
*../python3.3/subprocess.py line 847*

```
def _translate_newlines(self, data, encoding):
    data = data.decode(encoding)
    return data.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n")
```

The `encoding` value is `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. I've saved the template files as UTF-8, along with the .po file(s).

Here's is the .po header *(just the skeleton created automatically from makemessages)*:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-02-28 22:42+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

This worked before (same files) under Python 2.7 and Django 1.5

---

**Update #2**

- List item
- Created a new naked project *(django-admin.py startproject blah)*
- Enabled i18n, etc.
- Created a single translation *(just in settings.py)*
- Ran `makemessages -l de
- Py2.7 (#python manage.py makemessages -a) works as expected
- Py3.3 (#python3 manage.py makemessages -a) fails

Possibly filing a bug, will update.

Comment: Do the charset headers contain the correct values in the .po files?

Comment: "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n" is what's in the .po header. I've added some print statements to subprocess.py (part of the stacktrace) and it's getting an encoding of ANSI_X3.4-1968

Comment: Creating a new project with a single translation gives me the same grief. Works with Py 2.7, not 3.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This threw me off as everything was fine with Py2, but not Py3, so I assumed that's where the problem would be.

The issue was in part because I'm using Docker, and running `makemessages` from within the container which didn't have the locale set to anything in particular for bash.

Things I tried:

- Saving files with UTF-8 *(with and without BOM)*
- Ensuring I had `UTF-8` in the header of the `.po` files
- Creating a new blank slate project
- Re-creating all `.po` files using Py3 *(as they were originally created with Py2)*

The top exception was being thrown in subprocess.py on this line 847:

```
def _translate_newlines(self, data, encoding):
    data = data.decode(encoding)
    return data.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n")
```

The encoding being passed in was `ANSI_X3.4-1968`, which was weird as I had saved the files as UTF-8 etc *(it was being set as ANSI... due to my bash session not have a locale set specifically)*.

**Answer**
In my Docker container I had no locale settings set in the terminal, so they were:

```
# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

These were my available locales *(missing my specific locale, `en_US.UTF-8`, but as long as it's UTF-8 I'm okay)*:

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

Placed this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
```

And now I get `UTF-8` as the content type within `subprocess.py`, and everything works with Py3/Django1.6  =)

long story short, I was caught off guard that Django/subprocess.py is using the environment locale, and not the encoding of the file / or the header Content-Type.

Comment: Why not place the env variables into the Dockerfile?