# UnicodeError error when calling Django i18n makemessages command

Tags: python, django, utf-8, translation

I'm working with Django's internationalisation features to generate translation strings for a webapp.

A problem is arising where I try and call `makemessages`, and the existing language `.po` file contains a special character (such as `$`, `£`, etc).

Where one of these exists, makemessages tries to load the existing `.po` file and to decode it. When it does this, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 18, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 325, in handle
   self.write_po_file(potfile, locale)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 458, in write_po_file
   msgs, errors, status = gettext_popen_wrapper(args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 51, in gettext_popen_wrapper
   stdout = stdout.decode(stdout_encoding)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
   return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa2' in position 2105: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to dig back through the traceback here, but I'm at a loss as to what's happening.

It seems as though Django tries to decode the existing `.po` file as `UTF8`, but then when re-encoding it, it's using an `ASCII` codec.

Any insights as to what's wrong would be massively appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

- OS: Ubuntu 15.10 and OS X 10.11.6
- Python: 2.7.10 and 2.7.11
- Django: 1.8.14
- Six: 1.10.0

I've tried reinstalling Django/Six as suggested, but the error is still there.

Ubuntu's `localedef --list-archive`:

```
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Content-type of the problematic translation file:

```
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106777/unicode-issue-with-makemessages-all-django-1-6-2-python-3-3

Comment: Try this: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 python manage.py makemessages`; does it work?

Comment: @nobe4: Does it make a difference when you run it with `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 python manage.py makemessages`? And, BTW, what is your operating system and version?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: sorry for the delay, this command doesn't solve the problem. I've updated my question with details.

Comment: Why do you mention two operating systems? You have the same error in both?

Comment: Yes, it's the OS of another dev. We have the same error.

Comment: Could you show the output of `localedef --list-archive`? This will work on the Ubuntu; I'm not certain about the Mac OS X.

Comment: Updated, not found on OSX though, if I found it, I'll add.

Comment: Please show the output of `grep Content-Type path-to-the-problematic-po-file`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129258/discussion-between-nobe4-and-antonis-christofides).

Answer (score 3):

*Note this is a different exception location from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106777/unicode-issue-with-makemessages-all-django-1-6-2-python-3-3) mentioned in the comments.*

It seems to me the only way this can happen is if there's been a modification to your django install or there's a bug in the python 2.7 version.

Your stack is:

```
> msgs, errors, status = gettext_popen_wrapper(args)
> stdout = stdout.decode(stdout_encoding)
```

`gettext_popen_wrapper` (on **django 1.8**, which is what I think you're using, can you confirm?) and `popen_wrapper` which creates `stdout` (after removing comments/docstrings and reindenting for clarity, see [popen_wrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.16/django/core/management/utils.py#L13) and [gettext_popen_wrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.16/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L35) on github for the unadulterated code):

```
def popen_wrapper(args, os_err_exc_type=CommandError, universal_newlines=True):
    try:
        p = Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
                close_fds=os.name != 'nt', universal_newlines=universal_newlines)
    except OSError as e:
        strerror = force_text(e.strerror, DEFAULT_LOCALE_ENCODING,
                              strings_only=True)
        six.reraise(os_err_exc_type, os_err_exc_type('Error executing %s: %s' %
                    (args[0], strerror)), sys.exc_info()[2])
    # NB: subprocess.Popen.communicate() should return two bytes 
    # (i.e. str in python 2) objects
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    return (
        output,
        force_text(errors, DEFAULT_LOCALE_ENCODING, strings_only=True),
        p.returncode
    )

def gettext_popen_wrapper(args, 
                          os_err_exc_type=CommandError, 
                          stdout_encoding="utf-8"):
    manual_io_wrapper = six.PY3 and stdout_encoding != DEFAULT_LOCALE_ENCODING

    stdout, stderr, status_code = popen_wrapper(
        args, os_err_exc_type=os_err_exc_type,
        universal_newlines=not manual_io_wrapper)

    if manual_io_wrapper:
        stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(stdout), encoding=stdout_encoding).read()
    if six.PY2:
        # EXCEPTION HIT ON THE FOLLOWING LINE
        stdout = stdout.decode(stdout_encoding)
    return stdout, stderr, status_code
```

So `stdout` should be a plain `str` object (i.e. a bunch of bytes needing decoding) by the time we call `stdout.decode()`. However, if that were the case then why is the exception in **en**coding? We would only need to encode if the object already was a unicode object, i.e. if it was of type `unicode`. And sure enough, if we add the line

```
stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

before

```
stdout = stdout.decode(stdout_encoding)
```

Then now the `decode` method first attempts to `encode` the unicode `stdout`, using the [default encoding of ascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode), which causes the exception you've seen. I also got the same error by setting `manual_io_wrapper` to `True`, which caused the `stdout = io.TextWrapper(...)` line to happen as well (which produces a unicode as well), but that shouldn't be `True` because you're on python 2 not 3.

So I think either:

- You've got a bad install of `django` or `six`, or it's been edited. Try reinstalling them.
- You've hit a bug in `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` and for some reason it's returning a `unicode` not a `str` (I believe in python 3 that is possible if [`universal_newlines` are turned on](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). You may get mileage by reinstalling python or upgrading to a later version.

My main point though is that I don't think it's an environment issue. It would be interesting to know for any follow-ups:

- what platform you're on
- what python 2.7 you're using
- what django you're using.

Answer (score 0):

At the following line, somehow, `stdout` is not byte `str` but its `unicode` and you are getting exception during implicit encoding of that `unicode`.

```
stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

That's because of the fact that `decode()` should be performed on byte `str` and when we try calling `decode` on `unicode`, in python 2.7, there will be an implicit call to `encode` with that `unicode` before the `decode`, and this call to `encode` will be using default `charset` which is `ascii` in python.

```
unicode.encode() --> byte   # results in str
byte.decode() --> unicode   # results in unicode
unicode.decode() --> unicode.encode().decode()  # implicit encode call
```

So, start investigation with what's causing stdout to be `unicode`.

Thanks.